# How to change gif file to png file using python pil

Tags: python, image, python-imaging-library

this is my code :

```
import Image,glob

files = glob.glob("/small/*.gif") 

for imageFile in files:
    print "Processing: " + imageFile
    try:
        im = Image.open(imageFile)
        im.save( "/small_/", "png" )
    except Exception as exc:
        print "Error: " + str(exc)
```

but it show error :

```
  File "f.py", line 13
    im.save( "/small_/", "png" )
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

so what can i do ,

thanks

**updated:**

```
import Image,glob,os

files = glob.glob("small/*.gif") 

for imageFile in files:
    filepath,filename = os.path.split(imageFile)
    filterame,exts = os.path.splitext(filename)
    print "Processing: " + imageFile,filterame
    im = Image.open(imageFile)
    im.save( 'small_/'+filterame+'.png','PNG')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try copy and pasting your code in here back into your editor, it works perfectly fine for me.
You seem to have some non-printable characters  in there or something similar.

Also, have a look at the [PIL documentation](http://www.pythonware.com/library/pil/handbook/image.htm), `save` needs a filename or fileobject, not a folder.

Answer (score 1):

This is a python code that converts all`.gif` files in a folder `/gifs/` into `.gif.png` files:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont #dynamic import


import os
rootdir = 'gifs'
extensions = ('.gif')

for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(rootdir):
    for file in files:
        ext = os.path.splitext(file)[-1].lower()
        if ext in extensions:
            print (os.path.join(subdir, file))

            gif=os.path.join(subdir, file)
            img = Image.open(gif)
            img.save(gif+".png",'png', optimize=True, quality=100)
```

Source: https://gist.github.com/Kennyl/5854a11a0793a90fc8ea6c4746ff9720

Answer (score 0):

One thing you should fix is adding a filename to `save`: `im.save("/small_/" + filename_you_make_up + ".png", "png")`. That shouldn't be responsible for the syntax error though, but it will fix your next problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is a python code that converts a file named `a.gif` in folder `/gifs/` into `a.gif.png`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont #dynamic import

gif='gifs/a.gif'
img = Image.open(gif)
img.save(gif+".png",'png', optimize=True, quality=100)
```

Source: https://gist.github.com/Kennyl/5854a11a0793a90fc8ea6c4746ff9720